# acts-as-taggable-on tag cloud problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, acts-as-taggable-on

i'm new to rails. There is one question about this plugin. I've read the official readme file, and few other topics, but I still can't make it work.
I have installed it, it works perfectly for creating tags, but I can't make **tagcloud**

I've done

```
 module SitesHelper
    include ActsAsTaggableOn::TagsHelper
  end

      class SiteController < ApplicationController
  def tag_cloud
      @tags = Site.tag_counts_on(:tags)
  end
      end
```

And the view throws me exeption on

```
  <% tag_cloud(@tags, %w(css1 css2 css3 css4)) do |tag, css_class| %>
    <%= link_to tag.name, { :action => :tag, :id => tag.name }, :class => css_class %>
  <% end %>
```

wrong number of arguments (at least 1)

```
24: <b>Tags:</b>
25:     <%= @site.type_list %>
26:     
27:   <% tag_cloud @site.type_list, %w(css1 css2 css3 css4) do |tag, css_class| %>
28:     <%= link_to tag.name, { :action => :tag, :id => tag.name }, :class => css_class %>
29:   <% end %>
30:
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I think it adds methods to the classes, so you can directly access them.

You could try this:

```
        <h2>Tag Cloud</h2>
    <% if Site.tag_counts.length > 0 -%>
        <% tag_cloud Site.tag_counts, %w(css1 css2 css3 css4) do |tag, css_class| -%>
            <%= link_to tag.name, home_tag_path(tag), :class => css_class -%>
        <% end -%>
    <% else -%>
        <%= content_tag :p, 'No tags' -%>
    <% end -%>
```

That is what I have used and it works.

N.B. when you call tag_cloud from within the sites view, it is calling the corresponding definition in the controller. You want to call the tag_cloud in tags_helper (in the plugin), so you'll wantt to remove your tag_cloud definition in your controller as well.

Some good topics to cover that might help understand this are:

- Method lookup (one step to the right,
  then up) and
- Self (good to understand fully if starting on ruby/rails)
- Metaprogramming (if you aren't familiar with the term)

All are good to get your head around if you are new to ruby/rails.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem with this example myself.
And a few other problems as well.
I fixed what I ran into to work for my needs even though they may stray slightly from the original intention.

I fixed it by moving `@tags = Site.tag_counts_on(:tags)` into the index method. I then removed the tag_cloud method. (It wasn't restful anyway.)

I also changed the link_to to redirect to the controller for the items that were tagged.
That involved:

- setting the text to tag.name
- changing the path
- removing `:action => :tag` and `:id => :tag.name`
- adding a key value identifier to be passed in through params

I also changed the tag classes to something less generic.

My finished controller method:

```
def index
  @list = List.new
  @tags = List.tag_counts_on(:tags)
end
```

My finished view snippet:

```
<% tag_cloud(@tags, %w(tag1 tag2 tag3 tag4)) do |tag, css_class| %>
  <%= link_to tag.name, lists_path(:id => tag.name), :class => css_class
```